# Atomで、 選択、又はカーソルのある要素に対して、任意のHTMLタグで囲む ショートカットキーはありますか？

Tags: atom-editor

Atomで、
選択、又はカーソルのある要素に対して、任意のタグで囲む
ショートカットキーはありますか？

Comment: HTMLのタグを想定していますか？

Comment: はいそうです！HTMLです！失礼しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

私の知る限りデフォルトの機能では「選択文字列を別の文字列でラップする」ものはありませんが、そういうことができるようにするプラグインはあります。

たとえば [atom-wrap-in-tag](https://atom.io/packages/atom-wrap-in-tag) や [atom-tag-wrapper](https://atom.io/packages/atom-tag-wrapper) はそのためのプラグインです。AtomのSettingsからPluginを検索してインストールすると使えるようになります。キーコンフィグも設定から自分の好みで変えられます(これはAtomに元々ついている機能です)。

他にも [emmet.io](https://emmet.io/) のAtom実装である [emmet-atom](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet-atom) の機能の一部や、[vim-surround](https://atom.io/packages/vim-surround) でも同じようなことができます。お好みのものをお選びください。

---

また、AtomのHTML用デフォルト機能としてこういうことができるようにしようという[issueが立っています](https://github.com/atom/language-html/issues/9)。その内Atomのデフォルト機能になるかもしれません。